# Command linux xsltproc not found in a script

Tags: linux, bash

I use the command line from SAP command line system.
The direct command xsltproc works.
When I use it in a script placed in a directory  /usr/sap/trans/command, there is a message "command not found".
Here is the script

```
file="/shared/TQ1/ATA/IN/filelist.txt"
echo "$file second"
echo "param $1"
#find /shared/TQ1/ATA/INTER -type f *.xml > /shared/TQ1/ATA/IN
echo "\n after find"
couc=`date +%y%m%d`
file2=$file
echo "&couc"
echo "`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S%N`"
echo "file2=$file2"
echo "before xsltproc"
xsltproc -o /shared/TQ1/ATA/OUT/integrity.xml /usr/sap/trans/command/ATADecrypt_integrity.xsl /shared/TQ1/ATA/INTER/ataLocalizationXML.xml
echo "after xsltroc"
#echo "\n sortie"
```

The variable  couc is not affected
couc=`date +%y%m%d`
It seems that the script can't access to the system variable date
but when I use echo "`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S%N`" I receive 211003112644437803137 with the script

I call the script
with
sh /usr/sap/trans/command/myscript.sh
or
bash /usr/sap/trans/command/myscript.sh

outputfile after execution of script

```
/shared/TQ1/ATA/IN/filelist.txt
 second
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       param 
/shared/TQ1/ATA/INTER/ataLocalizationXML.xml
                                                                                                                                                                                                            \n after find
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &couc
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
211003125447931677292
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         file2
=/shared/TQ1/ATA/IN/filelist.txt


                                                                                                                                                                                                                       before xsltproc
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               warning: failed 
to load external entity "/shared/TQ1/ATA/INTER/ataLocalizationXML.xml
"                                                                                                                                                                        unable to parse /shared/TQ1/ATA/INTER/ataLocalizationXML.xml
                                                                                                                                                                                                  after xsltroc
```

Be careful. Check the result of the all the file (to right of the screen).

Comment: It would be helpful if you would cut & paste the exact output of a run of your script into the question.  Along with the exact command used to run the script to produce that output.

Comment: I added the file of output in the post. 
Be careful, the output is like that because that comes from SAP interface, but that is the OS linux which reply that

Comment: The error reported in that output is a failure to parse `/shared/TQ1/ATA/INTER/ataLocalizationXML.xml` (as XML).  It is possible that some higher-level component that attempts to run the script reports that incorrectly as "command not found", but that does not appear to be the root problem.

Answer (score 7):

xsltproc: XSLT 1.0 command line processor

XSLT is an XML language for defining transformations of XML files from XML to some other arbitrary format, such as XML, HTML, plain text, etc. using standard XSLT version 1.0 stylesheets. This package contains a command line tool that facilitates XSLT transformations.

Install the `xsltproc` package to get rid of the error "xsltproc not found". Installation instructions differ depending on one's operating system, but here are some examples:

- Debian/Ubuntu/apt-based       `apt-get install xsltproc`
- Alpine       `apk add libxslt`
- Arch Linux   `pacman -S libxslt`
- CentOS       `yum install libxslt`
- Fedora       `dnf install libxslt`
- OS X         `brew install libxslt`
- Docker       `docker run cmd.cat/xsltproc xsltproc`

Answer (score 0):

About the `Command not found` error, that means that the `xsltproc` file was not found in the execution of the script via the PATH environment variable, please update your script to use the full PATH of the `xsltproc` file.

```
# Please run the following command to the the full PATH then adjust your script and let us know the result.
$ which xsltproc
```